# Exit with error code from SPSS syntax

Tags: spss

I am using a batch file which calls an SPSS production job which runs many syntax files.

In the syntax files I want to able to check some variables, and if certain conditions are not met then I want to stop the production job, exit SPSS and return an error code to the batch file.

The batch file needs to stop running the next commands based on the error code returned. I know how to do this in the batch file already.

The most basic solution could be if the error code is not 0 then stop, and the error text will be output to a separate text file from within the syntax. A bonus would be a different error code which I could then match to where in the syntax that code is thrown.

What is the best way to achieve this in the SPSS syntax and or production file?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to execute Statistics as an external mode Python job.  Then you could interrogate any results, catch exceptions, and set exit codes and messages however, you like.  Here is an example:

jobs.py:

## Python jobs

import sys
sys.path.append(r"""c:/spss23/python/lib/site-packages""")
import spss

try:
    spss.Submit("""INSERT FILE="c:/temp/syntax1.sps".""")
except:
    print "syntax1.spss failed"
    exit(code=1)

try:
    spss.Submit("""INSERT FILE="c:/temp/syntax2.sps".""")
except:
    print "syntax1.spss failed"
    exit(code=2)

Then the bat file would do
python c:/myjobs/jobs.py
print %ERRORLEVEL%

or similar.  The job would need to save the output in appropriate format using OMS or shell redirection.  (The blocks after try and except should be indented.)

Comment: How would SPSS syntax throw an exception then?

Comment: If there is a severity 3 or higher error in the submitted SPSS  commands, a Python exception is raised.  Sev 3 and up means that a command failed.  Levels 1 and 2 are just warnings that let the command complete.  There is an api for getting the errorlevel if you want finer control, but you would need to Submit the commands one by one for it to be useful.

Comment: Don't understand how that answers my question?
I want SPSS to throw an exception. I want that somewhere in the SPSS syntax I can have a condition that creates an error.

Comment: The Submit api will get an exception if there is a problem in the SPSS syntax.  Since the top level job  here is the Python code, exiting from Python with a nonzero error code will show up in the %ERRORLEVEL% in your bat file.  So the chain is an error in executing the SPSS code is propagated to the controlling Python code which exits the job with a nonzero code.  The Python code might handle the error and continue or it could exit.

Comment: Still don't think you get my question. There is no error in the SPSS code. The SPSS code works fine. I want to create an error in certain situations. For example IF variable2 = 6 then throw an error and exit. Why? Because I don't want variable2 to contain 6. Again, the SPSS syntax is fine. I want to manually create an error.

Comment: So the SPSS code is correct, but you want the job to stop under certain circumstances.   You would need to use blocks of Python code for these conditions.  The VALIDATEDATA command or other code might be able to check the conditions, but you would need to use Python to interrogate the result and stop the job.  Or you could do this directly in Python code, but you would need to run in external mode, i.e., Python driving Statistics, in order to actually stop the job with an error code.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In external mode, you could use code like this or you could interrogate items in the Viewer.

```
import spss, spssdata

curs = spssdata.Spssdata("variable2")  
for case in curs:  
    if case[0] == 6:  
        exit(99)  
curs.CClose
```